# Computing relative directions

Tags: calculus, physics

I'd like to ask your help for this problem:
I have two bearings. These bearings are angle of direction from $-180$ to $+180$ degrees. One is between my current position $(A)$ and 
a target $(T)$. 
One is between my previous position $(P)$ and my current position $(A)$. 
I'd like to obtain a third one with the relative direction considering the 
direction I'm moving.

I try to explain better:

If I walk from south to north and my target is on the west (my left side), 
the bearing will be $-90$ degrees. But if I walk from north to south and the target is on 
west is on my right side, so bearing should be $+90$.

I tried to find a formula to obtaing this direction, but I'm not successful with it. 
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that current bearing has north being $0$, west being $-90$ and east being $90$, and you want the relative bearing (with straight ahead being $0$, left being $-90$ and right being $90$), then the formula is simply relative bearing $=$ target bearing minus current bearing, then adding or subtracting 360 as needed to bring the relative bearing back in the range $[-180, 180]$.

For instance, if your current bearing is $45$ (northeast) and the target bearing is $-45$, then the relative bearing is $-45 - 45 = -90$, or left.  Second example: Current bearing is $-90$ (west), target bearing is $135$ (southeast), then relative bearing is $135-(-90) = 225$, then subtract $360$ to get $225-360 = -135$ (rear left).

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot. So, if I well understood: bearing = target - current. If the result is < -180 I add 360. If it is > 180 I subtract 360. Thanks

Comment: Yes, depending on your conventions.  Check a few cases to make sure that our conventions agree.  If they work out, please accept the answer.